# when i add where on an eloquent object it carry previous where clause

Tags: laravel

This is the CODE snippet :

```
$records   =   \Spot\Shipment\Models\Order::orderBy('id', 'desc');
 DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log
 $total  =   $records->count();
 $new   =   $records->where('requested',0)->count();
 $delivered_paid   =   $records->where('requested',41)->count();
 // Your Eloquent query executed by using get()

dd(DB::getQueryLog()); // Show results of log 
exit;
```

I expect `$records->where('requested',41)->count();` line will only add one where clause like:  `WEHRE requested = 41`. But it produces `WHERE requested = 0 and requested = 41`. It proves $records object remember previously initiated method attribute and carry forward. This may be the default behavior. How can I break this and get my expected outcome?

Comment: If you have written two `where` then ofcourse it will give you this result. What exactly you want ? it will repeat itself unless you place an `if ` condtion among the `where` conditions

Comment: I want  $records->where('requested',0)->count(); this will return number of records satisfying `requested` = 0. Then $records->where('requested',41)->count(); will return satisfying `requested` = 41 but it returns based on `requested` = 0 AND `requested` = 41.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line creates a **Query Builder** type object:

`$records   =   \Spot\Shipment\Models\Order::orderBy('id', 'desc');`

This object builds a query, it is a single object. Every time you call `where` on that object you are "building a query" (adding to the query you are building). If you want a clean query you want a new builder object.

A possible solution is to clone the original builder and add conditions to those objects and use them to execute your queries:

```
$somerecords = (clone $records)->where(...)->count();
$otherquery = (clone $records)->where(...)->count();
```

Though in your particular case you probably don't have any special conditions added to the original query you are building so you can just go in the static way to get a new builder instance:

```
$something = YourModel::where(...)->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use The Model to get your expected result like this:

```
 $new   =   \Spot\Shipment\Models\Order::where('requested',0)->count();
 $delivered_paid   =   \Spot\Shipment\Models\Order::where('requested',41)->count();
```

Let me know if it helps: